# Import csv file in excel scrambles characters

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file that I created myself out of a `python script`. I'm struggling with encoding. The csv file is encoded in `utf-8` with unix style line endings. TI"m on a german macos machine. Now I'm trying to import the file via the `data` dialog of excel. All over the internet one can find that to solve this problem one has to choose `65001 utf-8` as `file origin`. Unfortunately my `Excel 2011` copy does not offer that exact option. The closest to that option is `Unicode 9.0 UTF-8`. This option converts the file entry `1999-2000` to `1999__2000`. So which format should I use to have the text displayed correctly? Another possibility is to change the encoding of the file on creation, which one should I choose?

Comment: Try hitting the evil at its root. Search the Internet for understanding which encoding your _Python_ Dynamic Interpreted Programming Language is producing.